# Implement thread safe ctime function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, time

ANSI C time function are not thread safe: in particular `gmtime`, `ctime` and `strftime`. For what I know the only thread-safe function is `time`.

If I'm right in Visual Studio this function are all thread safe. I'm using MinGW compiler (4.8.0 with dwarf-2, that one provided by Qt 5.1.0 ).

How can inplement thread safe function of `gmtime_r`, `ctime_r` and `strftime_r`? Or is there a more thread-safe library for that?

I'm using C++11 as default language.

**edit 1** 
I'm using MinGW 4.8.0 (posix, dwarf-2) on windows xp.

**edit 2** 
I'm considering to use Boost.DateTime may it be a good choice?

I'm very disappointed for the lack on c++11 of time managment!

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have a standard POSIX library available, as otherwise you would already have [`ctime_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ctime.html) et al. And with C++11 you have the [`std::chrono` namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: I'm using MinGW on Windows Xp. And it does not provide this functions... so I've to implement it myself.

Answer (score 2):

There actually should be `gmtime_r` and `ctime_r` in `pthread.h` but they are temporary removed because of a bug (http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1625/).

You have few choices

1. Wait until it will be fixed
2. Use older version of MiniGW
3. Make a reentrant wrapper for all of those functions using `lock_guard` just like `safe_increment` has done [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)
4. And maybe best way is to use functions form `chrono` header file added by C++11

Comment: unfortunatly `std::chrono` doesnt't sutisfy my requests: I need given a time_t set the O.S. time ( both in windows and linux with `SetSystemTime` and `settimeofdat`). And older versione of MinGW doesn't help. I'm using all last c++11 features

Comment: I'm guessing that setting system time is much "expansive" operation then locking so try std::lock_guard.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW arleady provide both gmtime_r and gmtime_s function, but they are note in the `std` namespace.