# deadlock in multi-threaded program between malloc and ctime_r

Tags: c++, multithreading, time, deadlock, standard-library

I have a C++ program (running on Linux - Ubuntu 12.04 - gcc compiler), and i am getting a deadlock between 2 threads

```
T1 backtrace: 
#0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:93
#1  0x00007f24bd454251 in _L_lock_10628 () at malloc.c:5253
#2  0x00007f24bd451f77 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=139793535074336) at malloc.c:2921
#3  0x00007f24bd457da2 in __GI___strdup (s=0x7f24bd54a4c2 "/etc/localtime") at strdup.c:43


T2 backtrace: 
#0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:93
#1  0x00007f24bd480ee4 in _L_lock_2180 () at tzset.c:616
#2  0x00007f24bd480cf7 in __tz_convert (timer=0x7f24bd789ee8, use_localtime=1, tp=0x7f2455a0bc70) at tzset.c:619
#3  0x00007f24bd47e570 in ctime_r (t=<optimized out>, buf=0x7f2455a0bcf0 "\364\230\005\277$\177") at ctime_r.c:29
```

T2 is called from a static library i am using. 
I also read ctime_r is not thread-safe.

How can i avoid deadlock on such case ?

Comment: `ctime_r` is quite specifically a thread-safe version of `ctime`. Did you really read that `ctime_r` is _not_ thread-safe, and if so, where? (btw longer backtraces might help to pinpoint the real cause of the problem).

Comment: You can "avoid deadlock" by providing the piece of code in question allowing people to help you, if possible.

Comment: Sorry 
you are right - i read about ctime
here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048012/implement-thread-safe-ctime-function

Comment: I can not supply actual code because some of it is in a library i have no access to it source. However - in this case i can see from my backtrace that this 2 threads are writing to log and use 2 different methods to get timestamp